# Error in create database postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql

Is any way to check a database is already exists or not in PostgreSQL?

Iam a new one in PostgreSQL.
And also need to check it from my java application via jdbc driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternate solution for this problem. By using the following query :

```
       ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("select count(*) from pg_catalog.pg_database where datname = 'sample'") ;
       res.next();
       int count = res.getInt("count");
       System.out.println("Count : " + count);
       if(count == 0) {
         st.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE sample");
       }
```

Its work fine

Answer (score 3):

There is no `IF NOT EXISTS` option for `CREATE DATABASE` in PostgreSQL. See [`CREATE DATABASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdatabase.html).

You can check `pg_database` to see if the DB exists, and only attempt to create it if it does not.

You would need to do this via [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html), because of the limitation Frank points out in the comments:

```
regress=> SELECT create_database_if_not_exists('test');
ERROR:  CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "CREATE DATABASE test"
PL/pgSQL function create_database_if_not_exists(text) line 6 at EXECUTE statement
```

Comment: This is what I get on 9.1: "CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed from a function or multi-command string"

Comment: @FrankHeikens Teach me for not testing all the cases; I checked the function syntax with an existing DB but didn't actually create one.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you do not have many databases made in postgreSQL
Here is a simple way to see what databases you have and do not have

Can use pgadmin ,and expand database column and see what databases you have and dont have.

[image]

As shown by the yellow box, the databases created in pgadmin, by me, can try this